# Почему не стилизируется?

Tags: bootstrap

Просто слева пишет лого, справа пишет четыре "привета", без какой-либо авто стилизации

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Страничка</title>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <div class="navbar-brand">ЭтоЛого
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Привет</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Привет</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Привет</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Привет</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!--<div class = "container-fluid">
            <div class = "row">
                <div class ="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-8 col-lg-6 " style = "background-color:cyan" >Левый</div>
              <div class ="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-md-4 col-lg-6 " style = "background-color:darkorange" >Правый</div>
              </div>
          </div>-->

  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Как сверстали, то и видите. Тут не должно быть никаких других стилей. Это стандартные стили бутсрапа, вы их подключили.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Страничка</title>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <div class="navbar-brand">ЭтоЛого
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Привет</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Привет</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Привет</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Привет</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        а если добавить другие элеметы в вашу верстку<br>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark">Например стандартная темная кнопка бутсрапа</button>
        <br>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12">
        <br> Прогресс-бар:
        <br>
        <div class="progress">
          <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 41%" aria-valuenow="41" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12">
        <br>
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header">
            Карточка
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Видите,</h4>
            <p class="card-text">
              Все работает</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!--<div class = "container-fluid">
            <div class = "row">
                <div class ="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-8 col-lg-6 " style = "background-color:cyan" >Левый</div>
              <div class ="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-md-4 col-lg-6 " style = "background-color:darkorange" >Правый</div>
              </div>
          </div>-->

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```